# How to set a general price for all variable of product? (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the plugin WooCommerce. I want to enter the same price for all variations of goods. To do this we have to manually set the price for each option.

How to set the price once for all variants?

[image]

Comment: wrong forum, should be in wordpress stackexchange

Comment: @cyptus The **wordpress.stackexchange** community marks such questions [as an offtopic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce)": `Questions *specific* for this e-commerce plugin have their own forum at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce`.

Answer (score 7):

on the product variations page there is a drop down box (see below image). here you can manipulate the variations in bulk. This isn't really a coding question, you can find the answers in woo documents.

[image: edit variations image]

Answer (score 1):

With the latest versions of woocommerce you can set a common price for all variations at the Set Regular Prices option

Hello, this here should help.

-- https://www.gowp.com/blog/apply-the-price-of-a-woocommerce-product-variation-to-all-variations-of-the-same-product/

Answer (score 0):

[How to set Same price for all variation products"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrH4o.jpg)

1. using the dropdown displayed, select "Set regular prices"
2. A pop up will be displayed asking for the price you want to set for the variations
3. Enter the price and click Ok
4. Same price will be set for the variation product at once.

Thank you